# Unable to get the last object from json using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I'm not able to get the last object filtered after using `jq` select. To demonstrate this issue, I got the following simple json file that contains list of IP addresses:

file.json

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673146101"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673146107"
}
{
  "ip": "2.2.2.2",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673146109"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 10,
  "last_scan_date": "1673152750"
}
{
  "ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "tested_count": 11,
  "last_scan_date": "1673152755"
}
```

In order to list out the data for IP `1.1.1.1`, I will do the following in bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="1.1.1.1"
jq -r 'select(.ip=="'"${TARGET}"'")' file.json
```

The above will output:

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673146101"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673146107"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 10,
  "last_scan_date": "1673152750"
}
```

Now, what I want is the last output for this IP `1.1.1.1` with the last_scan_date `1673152750` .

So I tried one of these:

1. `jq -r 'select(.ip=="'"${TARGET}"'") | last' file.json` (does not work)

I got error:

```
> jq: error (at file.json:5): Cannot index object with number
> jq: error (at file.json:10): Cannot index object with number
> jq: error (at file.json:20): Cannot index object with number
```

2. `jq -r 'last(select(.ip=="'"${TARGET}"'"))' file.json` (does not work)
3. `jq -r 'select(.ip=="'"${TARGET}"'") | .[-1]' file.json` (does not work)
4. `jq -r 'select(.ip=="'"${TARGET}"'") | to_entries | last' file.json` (does not work)

The expected output is:

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 10,
  "last_scan_date": "1673152750"
}
```

I searched about this but mostly they are talking about getting the last array but I don't have array here just objects. Can jq actually do this?

Comment: Or perhaps, the json file should be reformatted to use `[` and `]`?

Comment: That would be a sub-optimal approach, at least w.r.t. memory utilization.  See instead @pmf's solution using `inputs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add arrays brackets beforehand. Either make the input stream an array by using the `-s` command-line option, and access the items with `.[]`, or use `inputs` to fetch the items (which requires the `-n` option). Then, `last` can give you the preferred item.

Using `-s` and `.[]`:

```bash
jq -sr --arg ip '1.1.1.1' 'last(.[] | select(.ip==$ip)).last_scan_date'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/th4ywl7dbKv)

Using `-n` and `inputs`:

```bash
jq -nr --arg ip '1.1.1.1' 'last(inputs | select(.ip==$ip)).last_scan_date'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Nk4Oy87HAC7)

Output:

```json
1673152750
```

Note: Use `--arg` to introduce external values.

Comment: What is the difference, the first one better than the second one ? Thank you.

Comment: @KalibZen The first one collects all items into an array, the second one just process the items one by one. Generally, the latter is preferred for processes which only look at single items individually (i.e. independent of the others), which happens to be also your use case. The `.[]` from the former approach does nothing but to destructure the array again. The effort to allocate the memory needed to hold the whole array at once for a second (or less) was therefore spent uselessly.